# MySql primary key doesn't consume any size

Tags: mysql, indexing, mysql-workbench, database-schema

I have those two tables schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  lat double NOT NULL,
  lng double NOT NULL,
  date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  mobile bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  date_updated datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_Datee` (`mobile`,`date`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_DeviceLocationss` FOREIGN KEY (`mobile`) REFERENCES `device` (`serial`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And here is the second one:

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable2` (
  lat double NOT NULL,
  lng double NOT NULL,
  date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  mobile bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  date_updated datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

  PRIMARY KEY `IDX_Datee2` (`mobile`,`date`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_DeviceLocationss2` FOREIGN KEY (`mobile`) REFERENCES `device` (`serial`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In every table there are around **4,000,000** records till now,
So I'm trying to build the most suitable schema which is more fast and less storage consuming.

When I check the state of each `Table` in `MySql Workbeanch` I got little confusing:

**First Table:**

[image]

**Second Table**

[image]

When I changed the `IDX_Datee` key from `Index` to `Primary`, It doesn't consume any space.

I believe the second schema is better for me, But I don't have a good understand about that difference.

Can anyone explain that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is index organized. The datarecords are stored in index order.
see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html

"With the InnoDB storage engine, the table data is physically organized to do ultra-fast lookups and sorts based on the primary key column or columns"

so there is no extra index necessary

Comment: So in this case the `Delete, Update` queries will toke long time, Right?

Comment: I am no mysql specialist, I know these IOTs from Sql-Server. I would say there should not be a great difference, updates should not have an adverse effect, since it is the primary key. Deletes and Inserts will need possibly more  effort in handling the data and less effort because of the one index less to keep updated. The big advantage is that each access via primary key normally needs less external operations, because all the data is already there.

Answer (score 1):

All operations (select, insert, delete, update) on a *single* row specified *by the PK* will be very fast and efficient.  Drill down the BTree that contains the data and is organized by the PK, and there is the row to work with.

The PK takes a tiny amount of space, just as any BTree is more than the leaf nodes.  As a Rule-Of-Thumb, MySQL's BTrees (data or index) have a fanout of about 100.  That is, each node has about 100 nodes under it.  This implies that there is only about 1% overhead for the non-leaf nodes for the 'rest' of the PK overhead.

16KB / 61 is about 268 -- your "fanout".

For starters, I will suggest that `DOUBLE` (8 bytes) is gross overkill for latitude and longitude unless you are trying to distinguish one flea from another on a dog.  Here is [*my table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices) of representation choices for lat/lng.

`INT` is 4 bytes.  If you are sure you won't go past 16 million, change the PK to `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (3 bytes).  (I suggest this is too risky.)

The size of the PK is doubly important because it is included in every secondary key.

If `(mobile, date)` is unique, the it may as well be the PK.  That shaves off *two* copies of `id`, *and* speeds up queries based on `mobile`.

If `mobile` contains phone numbers, well some numbers won't fit.  Better off going with `DECIMAL(11)` takes 5 bytes; `(13)` takes 6.  If, instead, `mobile` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` in some other table, the perhaps even `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes *per copy, per table*) would be better.

Your First table has 4 extra columns (relative to the Second table):  `id`--twice, `mobile`, and `date`.

Comment: Thank you, your information is more than good, But I don't understand from where you get `16KB` n the second part.

Comment: InnoDB blocks are 16KB.  All InnoDB data and indexes are stored in BTrees with 16KB blocks.  (See Wikipedia if you need a refresher on BTrees.)